# Is it possible to enable logging variables for unittest in python?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-logging

I'm new to using unittest with python, so probably a newbie question. I was wondering if there's a way to turn on logging of variables. I have a simple example below to cut out any logic issues.

```
    def return_statement(self):
        temp_var = 'stuff'
        return temp_var

    def test_return_statement(self):
        expected_return = 'stuff'
        output = self.return_statement()
        self.assertEqual(expected_return,output)
```

Since this is my first time using unittest I want to make sure the test functions are doing what I think they are doing. I have a lot more complicated functions in my code that have a lot of if-else paths, for loops, etc. So I'd like to be able to ensure that the unit test is running the test I think it's running. In this case it's just returning a variable, but I'd like my functions to print variables/log messages as needed.

**Edit** To give a concrete example, let's say I want to log the expected_return variable in test_return_statement, and the actual return value temp_var from return_statement.

Comment: You want to test the test? Make sure it's not getting recursive!

Comment: I'm not trying to test the test, but make sure it's running the right test.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You can do what ever you want in your test functions including logging. Please explain by giving an output example